# Issue sending Apple Push Notification when connected to APNS server in PHP

Tags: php, ios, apache, push-notification, apple-push-notifications

I have a PHP script to send push notifications. With the following script I get a "Successfully sent the message" confirmation yet the push notification does not send. Any thoughts on what the issue could be or any other PHP scripts that can be used?

```
$apnsServer = 'api.push.apple.com:443';

$privateKeyPassword = '<MY_PASSWORD>';

$message = 'You have a new comment!';

$deviceToken = '<A_DEVICE_TOKEN>';

$pushCertAndKeyPemFile = '<MY_PEM_FILE>.pem';
$stream = stream_context_create();
stream_context_set_option($stream,
'ssl',
'passphrase',
$privateKeyPassword);
stream_context_set_option($stream,
'ssl',
'local_cert',
$pushCertAndKeyPemFile);


$connectionTimeout = 20;
$connectionType = STREAM_CLIENT_CONNECT | STREAM_CLIENT_PERSISTENT;
$connection = stream_socket_client($apnsServer,
$errorNumber,
$errorString,
$connectionTimeout,
$connectionType,
$stream);
if (!$connection){
echo "Failed to connect to the APNS server. Error no = $errorNumber<br/>";
exit;
} else {
echo "Successfully connected to the APNS. Processing...</br>";
}
$messageBody['aps'] = array('alert' => $message,
'sound' => 'default',
'badge' => 2,
);
$payload = json_encode($messageBody);
$notification = chr(0) .
pack('n', 32) .
pack('H*', $deviceToken) .
pack('n', strlen($payload)) .
$payload;
$wroteSuccessfully = fwrite($connection, $notification, strlen($notification));
if (!$wroteSuccessfully){
echo "Could not send the message<br/>";
}
else {
echo "Successfully sent the message<br/>";
}
fclose($connection);
```

Comment: `fwrite()` returns the number of bytes written, it doesn't indicate whether or not the recipient has understood those bytes. I.e., your payload could be incorrectly formatted or lacking authentication credentials. You probably need to read back from the stream to get the response.

Comment: Thank you. I will look into that now.

Comment: How would I be able to read the stream? Sorry I haven't worked with streams in the past.